# Navbar Toggler not Working in Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, bootstrap-5

I am designing a responsive page with Bootstrap 5, but I am having problems with Navbar in the first place. The toggle button does not work at all, no items shown when clicks.

I had searched for official documents for solutions, but not helpful.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container bg-dark">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
            <button
                class="navbar-toggler"
                type = "button"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#menuItems"
                aria-controls="menuItems"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle Navigation"
            >
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't have `id="menuItems"` on the navbar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed up using id `menuItems` also you must using `navbar-dark` with `bg-dark`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container bg-dark">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#menuItems" aria-controls="menuItems" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menuItems">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you ver much, it's my fault. Can you plz help me check why the toggler icon does not show in my code? But it works in your code.

Answer (score -1):

It might not be working for you because you might not be having relevant javascript and css bundle in your index.html. It needs Javascript bundle because toogle works on javascript plugin function.

Please try adding below in your code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks. I did not down vote this answer, and it won't let me change it it. Anyway, this answer was correct, I need to include the js bundle to get the toggler working.